# Add placeholder text to selectize.js dropdown menu in plotly widget

Tags: javascript, jquery, r-plotly, selectize.js

I am using plotly with R to create interactive charts . Each of them includes a selective.js search widget, which combines an `<input>` text box with a dropdown menu. (See [here](https://selectize.github.io/selectize.js/) for an example.) I tell plotly to add the search widget by passing `selectize = TRUE` to `plotly::highlight()`. I want to include placeholder text in the `<input>` field -- is this possible?

Others have asked how to [change the selectize.js placeholder value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19143364/how-to-change-placeholder-of-selectize-js-dropdown) after a page is loaded. The posted solutions generally call for adding a little jquery to one's page, which I'm happy to do. But I cannot get the solutions to work. The problem may arise because I don't have control over how selectize.js, or any other aspect of the dropdown menu, is incorporated into the HTML document. (Plotly black-boxes that part.)

Here is minimal R code that demonstrates the problem:

```
library(plotly)
data(mtcars)
myData <- highlight_key(mtcars, ~rownames(mtcars), group = "Enter name of car")
myFig <- plot_ly(myData, x = ~wt, y = ~mpg) 
myFig <- highlight(myFig, selectize = TRUE)
myFig
```

This code creates an HTML page with a selective.js dropdown menu. The text "Enter name of car" appears above the `<input>` text box. But I want it to appear *in* the box -- that is, as placeholder text. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible:

```
library(plotly)
data(mtcars)
myData <- highlight_key(mtcars, ~rownames(mtcars))
myFig <- plot_ly(myData, x = ~wt, y = ~mpg) 
myFig <- highlight(myFig, selectize = TRUE)
htmlwidgets::onRender(
  myFig,
  "function (el) {

    // Get selectized search widget
    s = $('select')[0].selectize;

    // Update placeholder 
    s.settings.placeholder = 'Enter name of car'; 
    s.updatePlaceholder();
  
    // Hide group name (random string) that would appear above placeholder
    $('#htmlwidget_container').find('label').css('display', 'none');
  }")
```

Comment: Thanks! One small issue. The placeholder is only shown for the first plot if I have multiple plotly figures in a R Markdown file (e.g. if I copy the code above 2 times into the document). Is it possible to show it for all plots? Also the group name seems to still show up?